Understanding this formula in Thorne (1980)
I am studying this paper by Thorne:

Multipole expansions of gravitational radiation,

link to pdf
I am trying to figure out equation (2.12) pag. 11 which links the Symmetric Trace Free (STF) tensor to spherical harmonics. I report it here (notation from the paper):
$$\mathcal{Y}^{lm}_{k_1\dots k_l} = C^{lm} \sum_{j=0}^{[(l-m)/2]}a^{lmj} \, \Big(\delta^1_{(k_1}+i \delta^2_{(k_1}\Big)\cdots\Big(\delta^1_{k_m}+i \delta^2_{k_m}\Big)\delta^3_{k_{m+1}}\cdots\delta^3_{k_{l-2j}}\Big(\delta^{a_1}_{k_{l-2j+1}}\delta^{a_1}_{k_{l-2j+2}}\Big)\cdots\Big(\delta^{a_j}_{k_{l})}\delta^{a_j}_{k_{l})}\Big)$$
From eqn (2.11) a spherical harmonics can be written as:
$$Y^{lm}=\mathcal{Y}^{lm}_{k_L}N_{k_L}$$
where $N_i=\dfrac{x_i}{r}$ and
$$x_1+i x_2=\exp(i\phi)\sin(\theta), \qquad x_3=\cos(\theta).$$
So, as far as I understand, in (2.12) only the terms up to $\delta^3_{k_{l-2j}}$ are needed for rewriting the spherical harmonic according to the formula (2.7)
$$Y^{lm}=C^{lm}\, \Big( \exp(i\phi)\sin(\theta)\Big)^m \sum_{j=0}^{[(l-m)/2]} a^{lmj}(\cos(\theta))^{l-m-2j}.$$
(I have simply substituted the $N_i$ into the expression and obtained the various $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions)
Why are the other terms $\Big(\delta^{a_1}_{k_{l-2j+1}}\delta^{a_1}_{k_{l-2j+2}}\Big)\cdots\Big(\delta^{a_j}_{k_{l})}\delta^{a_j}_{k_{l})}\Big)$ needed? What are the indices $a_j$?

What are the indices $a_j$? They appear to be dummy indices being contracted.
